# Punctuation between clauses when the first clause is a series

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, dashes

I have this sentence:

> Even if I seem too busy, or you made a mistake, or someone we care about will be upset, or 
>   you feel embarrassed, if anything bothers you, I want to know.

I believe that it is correctly punctuated as is, right?

I have a style question... Would the sentence be easier to parse if there was a dash between *embarrassed* and *if* instead of a comma? And is that an accepted punctuation choice for a sentence like this?

> Even if I seem too busy, or you made a mistake, or someone we care about will be upset, or 
>   you feel embarrassed--if anything bothers you, I want to know.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes and yes, if you ask me. It should be a proper dash, though—not two hyphens.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I didn't know how to make a dash on this site, so I made do with two hyphens. What did you type for the dash to appear in your comment?

Comment: I simply typed a dash (`Opt` + `Shift` + `-` on my Mac; holding down the `-` key and choosing the em dash on my iPhone where I typed the comment; more tricky if you’re on a Windows machine, but holding down `Alt` and typing `0151` on the numeric keypad works).

Comment: Thanks for the tip—It's a whole new dash world for me now!

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me that way.  I would, however, get rid of all those extraneous uses of "or" to make:

> Even if I seem too busy, you made a mistake, someone we care about will be upset, or you feel embarrassed—if anything bothers you, I want to know.

edit: even better, I'd swap the clauses:

> If anything bothers you, I want to know–even if I seem too busy, you made a mistake, someone we care about will be upset, or you feel embarrassed.

Comment: I think the repetitive use of 'or' in the original sentence is a useful rhetorical device for emphasizing that *no matter what kind of obstacle might appear to stand in the way,* the speaker is willing to hear the other person's points. Swapping the order of the clauses works OK, though -- but I would still keep those *or*'s that you stripped out.

Comment: Good idea about swapping the clauses. I will run it past the author I'm working with.  And @ErikKowal, I agree the _or_'s work well here to emphasize the speaker's point.

Comment: Fair enough (regarding 'or').  Sometimes I get lost in efficiency and correctness.